# C#で自作したDLLを他のPCで設定する方法

Tags: c#, vbs, dll

お世話になります。

以前、とあるサイト様の情報を元に、C#で自作したDLLをVBAで使用するところまで
たどり着きました。
そこで、他のPCでも使用できるよう、そのサイト様の下の方の情報をもとに、VBSで
設定する方法を試してみたのですが、どうもうまくいきません。

http://excel.syogyoumujou.com/memorandum/dll_1.html

前回同様、こちらのサイト様の下の方に『別のパソコンでの設定』とあるのですが、
この方法でVBSのファイルを作成し、ドラッグ＆ドロップしても起動できません。

ドラッグ＆ドロップをしてDOS窓が立ち上がればもうレジストリの設定は完了したと
いうことなのでしょうか？それとも、この掲載されているVBSのコードが問題なのでしょうか？

ご教授ください。

よろしくお願いいたし幕す。

Comment: この辺 [エラー一覧とエラー処理のサンプルコード](https://bayashita.com/p/entry/show/76), [VBScript入門講座](http://vbscript.web.fc2.com/extra/error.html), [第9回　VBScriptのオブジェクトを使いこなす (2/4)](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0702/15/news122_2.html) の情報を元に発生したエラーの情報を取得し、行おうとしたこと・期待する結果・上手く行かなかった状況などの詳細を質問に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

Windowsには32bitと64bitがあります。作成したDLLは32bitですか 64bitですか それともAnyCPUですか？ 使用したRegAsmコマンドは32bitですか 64bitですか？ VBAすなわちExcelなどのアプリケーションは32bitですか 64bitですか？ これらが適切に一致しなければ使用できません。

VBSは問題の一端ですが、根本的には開発者が動作環境を正しく理解する必要があります。そして正しく理解したあかつきにはそもそもVBSを使用せずとも自身で[RegAsm.exeコマンド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool)を操作できるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。よくわかっていない状態で盲目的に信用しない方が良いということですね。ここに掲載されているVBSの使用はやめることにします。